# Open a website form a react-vr app contained in a iframe in the parent of the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, react-360

I have created a react-vr application and I want to integrate the vr app in a react website. As recommended I used a iframe to integrate the react-vr app in my website. As the following code depicts:

```html
export class LabyrinthPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <iframe
                src={"./src/Labyrinth/build/index.html"}
                style={{
                    position: 'fixed',
                    margin: 0,
                    padding: 0,
                    height:'100%',
                    width:'100%',
                    border:'none',
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Now I have a button in my react-vr application to go back to "/". But how to not open the webiste inside the `iframe`?

The button click should look somehow like?:

```html
              onBottonPress={() => {
                  Linking.openURL("/");
              }}
```

So I want to call "/" of my website from the react-vr application and open the link in the website that contains the iframe (not in the iframe). I tried to add `<base target="_parent"/>` in the header of my website but there was no effect.

Thanks for help